# Rep for Editing?

Tags: support

Do we get rep added to our profile for editing questions/answers on the Beta site?

I see +2 rep points on Stack Overflow when I make edits but no here on the EE site.

My **[profile tab for Revisions](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/users/28/mediagirl?tab=responses&sort=revisions)** only shows 3 revisions, but I've made a ton more edits than this on the main site. The profile preview, visible by hovering over the down arrow to the left of my name in the header, shows 0 revisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a user gains the [privilege of editing posts](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) (at 1000 rep), they no are no longer awarded reputation for edits. Up until that time any edits made by a user are moderated and, if approved, are worth +2 reputation.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the clarification.